# pm grant <PACKAGE_NAME> <PERMISSION_NAME> not working

Tags: android, shell, authorization, adb

I have a weird problem. Last week I had my code working like a charm. I'm working on a rooted tablet, and I'm setting Debug Mode on from code, but no idea why, I ran my app this morning and the command I'm using to to this doesn't work anymore, I get "Permission Denial etc.." BUT, when I type the command from my device's terminal, it works... Any help ?

```
private void grantPermission(){
    try {
        Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

        Log.e("PACKAGE", getPackageName());

        os.writeBytes("adb shell" + "\n");
        os.flush();

        os.writeBytes("pm grant "+getPackageName()+" android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" + "\n");
        os.flush();

        os.writeBytes("pm grant "+getPackageName()+" android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" + "\n");
        os.flush();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("SETTINGS", "FAIL");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it ever work from code? Also does it work again after you set it manually first?

Comment: Yes it did, and yes it does..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is! I finally fixed it out ! The permission wasn't set fast enough until the call, I simply added a call to the processe's waitFor() method and it worked again. But I still wonder why it used to work before !

```
private void grantPermission(){
    try {
        Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("pm grant "+this.getPackageName()+" android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" + "\n");
        os.writeBytes("pm grant "+this.getPackageName()+" android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" + "\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();

        suProcess.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```